# Update single variable in DirectX Shader

Tags: graphics, directx11, hlsl

I am trying to update a single variable within a CBuffer but I am unsure of how to do this.

I have a LightingBuffer which is passed to the GPU containing, ambient color, diffuse color etc and I want to be able to update the specularPower component of this CBuffer but not the rest.

In openGL I could just do glUniform1f and update it, however I cannot do this is DX / HLSL

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In DirectX 10.x/11.0, constant buffers are intended to be updated as a unit (i.e. you have to update the whole thing). This is why our performance recommendations is to arrange your data in constant buffers by frequency of update rather than having large cbuffers that contain variables that are updated frequently (per-object) and others that are updated occasionally (per-frame or on window size changes).

See [Windows to Reality: Getting the Most out of Direct3D 10 Graphics in Your Games](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/0/4/a04deeb2-d7e2-42a5-984a-9ea5c92bfeb2/Windows%20to%20Reality%20-%20Getting%20the%20Most%20out%20of%20Direct3D%2010%20Graphics%20in%20your%20Games.zip)

With DirectX 11.1 on Windows 8 or later, and appropriate drivers, you can make use of partial constant buffer updates with constant offsets. It's an optional hardware feature indicated by `D3D11_FEATURE_DATA_D3D11_OPTIONS.ConstantBufferPartialUpdate` and `D3D11_FEATURE_DATA_D3D11_OPTIONS.ConstantBufferOffsetting`. This allows you to use new parameters on `ID3D11DeviceContext1::XXSetConstantBuffers1` to achieve partial updates.

These optional hardware features are not supported with DirectX 11.1 on Windows 7. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj863687.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

From the question, this appears to be more a design problem rather than an API problem: **specular power is not a property of the light, it's a property of the surface**.  By including it in your light properties cbuffer you're creating an artificial coupling between these two different classes of property, and it's likely to cause you further problems in the future.

There are a few different ways you can solve this.

**Use a separate surface properties cbuffer**

Right now specular power might be the only surface property you want to change, but in the future you might want to add more.  Remember that cbuffer registers are groups of 4 floats (I'm deliberately ignoring other data types for the purpose of simplicity and clarity here) so if you update one float you effectively get 3 more float updates for free.

**Use instancing**

Add these per-surface properties to a per-instance buffer, adjust your input layout to match, and make a DrawInstanced or DrawIndexedInstanced call.  Pass the values directly from the VS to the PS if required.  Remember that *1 is a valid value for InstanceCount*.  We should also note here that *all draw calls in forthcoming APIs are instanced draw calls*, so this suggests that we don't need to worry about instancing overhead going forward: there is none.

**Encode specular power in a texture**

This is the most flexible method and would let you vary the power across a surface: some parts of the surface may have a different specular power to other parts.  It does of course come with the added cost of extra texture memory (but remember that it can be a lower-resolution texture) and an extra texture lookup (although you could abuse the alpha channel of an existing texture to hold it).  Again, if you ever need to expand to other surface properties you can use e.g a 4 channel RGBA texture with each channel holding a different property.